# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' in Python 3 using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** a website using python . But I am getting Following Errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\My PC Buddy\python\scraper\scraper.py", line 11, in 
link = product.find("a",{"class":"product-title"}).get('href')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

following is my Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl = "https://www.densoproducts.com/spark-plugs-denso"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
k = requests.get('https://www.densoproducts.com/spark-plugs-denso').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-item" })
productlinks = []
for product in productlist:
        link = product.find("a",{"class":"product-title"}).get('href')
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link)
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because `product` hadn't any `a` element with class of `product-title`.
I see the structure of site you want to crawl and I find out you should replace `a` with `h2` and then get `a` tag then `href` :

[image]

```py
for product in productlist:
        link = product.find("h2",{"class":"product-title"}).find('a').get('href')
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link)
```

Comment: i have completed the code . i am getting none in output could you please help

Comment: could you hep on following    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554566/getting-none-in-output-of-code-web-scrapping-python-3

Answer (score 1):

`class="product-title"` belongs to the `<h2>` tag, not the `<a>` tag.

The `find()` function returns None if nothing was found.

Comment: so which class I need to mention?